# I am trying to rewrite nginx address with a "?"

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to accomplish two things in regards to nginx rewrites. First is to rewrite something like this:

```
 oldvhost.domain.com/?dir=Dir1/Dir2/Dir3 -->
 newvhost.domain.com/?dir=./Dir1/Dir2/Dir3
```

Notice the "./" in front of the second vhost?

Secondly I am trying to rewrite something like this:

```
oldvhost.domain.com/orginal.php?file=Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/file.zip -> 
newvhost.domain.com/newphpfile.php?file=./Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/file.zip
```

I have managed to get this to work "somewhat" by doing this on the new vhost before any location commands:

```
 rewrite ^/original.php$ /newphpfile.php$1 last;
```

But this isn't working 100% and is only remedied by the `$realpath` PHP function. I still need this working via regex rewrite but there's something about the "?"s that are making it fail.

Comment: rewrite or redirect? cause you're changing the host.

Comment: 301 redirect to new directory link and file link. though I can do the 301 on the original vhost to the new vhost, and then worry about the rewrites on the new vhost.  it doesn't matter as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

As for the redirection you can do this in a location

```
location /something
  return 301 http://example.com/?dir=./$arg_dir;
}
```

Or if you want it as a rewrite

```
rewrite /old-example.com/location-from.php http://example.com/new-location.php?./$arg_dir permanent;
```

and for the rewrite it should be similar as the second redirection, but no need for full host name

```
rewrite /old-location.php /new-location.php?./$arg_dir;
```

And here's the [documentation of the `$arg_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_)

Comment: Running 1.4.4 compiled with pagespeed mod.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in Nginx would be a rewrite, using reg expressions.. Try the code below in your virtual host.

```
location / {
    #Rewrite for directory
    rewrite ^/?dir=(.*) http://yoururl.com/?dir=./$1;
    #rewrite for file
    rewrite ^/origional.php?file=(.*) http://yoururl.com/newphpfile.php?file=./$1;
}
```

The first rewrite takes care of your directory. Please note it is being assumed that all incoming links do not have the necessary ./ you need. If they come with the ./ it may cause breakage. Or it may cause nothing, depending on what the PHP is doing.